# Akka cluster sharding: do shard entities share a journal?

Tags: akka, persistence, sharding, persistent-storage, eventual-consistency

I am following an akka [tutorial](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-akka-video) demonstrating cluster sharding. In the cluster [sharding example](https://github.com/SalmaKhater/Learning-Akka/blob/84a9feb7dd530011e25796cb5f044c8b1ad63d3a/akka-cluster/src/main/scala/cluster-sharding/ShardingApp.scala), the author starts up a shared journal and makes the following comment:

```
// Start the shared journal one one node (don't crash this SPOF)
// This will not be needed with a distributed journal
```

the journal used [is](https://github.com/SalmaKhater/Learning-Akka/blob/84a9feb7dd530011e25796cb5f044c8b1ad63d3a/akka-cluster/src/main/resources/sharding.conf#L25):

```
journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb-shared"
```

1. Why do shard entities share a journal? my understanding is that Akka persistence doesn't support multiple writes but does support multiple reads. what is the need for a shared journal? I was under the impression that each persistent actor has its own journal. Why would the non-shared `LeveldbJournal` not support distribute reads? Is there any difficulty with doing that?
2. The tutorial is based on Akka 2.4 and in this version, cluster sharding uses `persistence` as a default for `akka.cluster.sharding.state-store-mode`. In this example, what component exactly uses the snapshop/journal support? is it the Persistent actor in different shards or it is information about the shards relating to its replication? What exactly needs to be distributed? I find the relevant documentation vague and confusing.
3. If I were to have only one shard, do I need to have a distributed journal?
4. A somewhat related question: I have [reimplemented](https://github.com/ShahOdin/QueryView/) the now deprecated PersistentView based on [`PersistenceQuery`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence-query.html). I can query the journal for the events from a persistentActor and setup a stream to receive its persisted events. I have tested it and it works. However I can't get it to receive the events in a sharded actor in my test environment with `InMemoryJournalStorage` (which I don't believe is a distributed journal). In my test scenario, I only have one shard and one actor and I use the unique `persistenceId` for the actor to query it, but I don't receive any events on the read side. Is there something I am missing about getting Akka persistence to work with cluster sharding? Should I be `append/prepend`ing the `persistenceId` used to query for events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They shouldn't, at least not in production code, see the warning note here:
   http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/persistence.html#shared-leveldb-journal

> A shared LevelDB instance is a single point of failure and should therefore only be used for testing purposes.

2. Both
3. Yes, if you wanted failover to work. If you didn't want failover and all you had was a single shard, then there would be no point using sharding at all.
4. Can't tell without seeing some of your code.

Comment: thanks. so re:4, so basically the environment, is one that I could get `PersistentView` to work in Akka 2.4 and now I am trying to replace it with `PersistenceQuery` based QueryView linked above.. I was trying to reproduce a minimal example but I was confused by the `LeveldbSharedJournal` thing. Regardless, your answers to the questions 1-3 seems to suggest that I should not really be mutating the persistence Id of the persistence-actor for the purposes of querying it from the journal plugin, is that right?